# Xcode 6 runtime attributes with Swift enums

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a class in Swift called `Button`:

```
enum ButtonBackgroundColor {
    case None
    case Yellow
}

class Button: UIButton {
    var backgroundColorType: ButtonBackgroundColor?
}
```

And then I'm setting a runtime attribute:

[image]

However, I get a non-descriptive crash. The stack trace mentions something about key value coding.

Runtime attributes do work however for non enum types, like Int or Float:

```
// runtime attributes work for this
var backgroundColorType: Int = 0
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm declaring my enum?

Comment: You've set your object in Interface Builder to be of your `Button` class, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your enum `ButtonBackgroundColor` includes a `.None` case, why not avoid declaring `backgroundColorType` in `Button` as an *optional*?  Doing so needlessly complicates the declaration.  Prefer

```
class Button: UIButton {
  var backgroundColorType = ButtonBackgroundColor.None
}
```

Besides being more idiomatically correct, the above might, just might, fix your 'user defined attribute' issue now that the variable is not an *optional*.

You also might need to provide raw values in your enum.  Like:

```
enum ButtonBackgroundColor : Int {
  case None = 0
  case Yellow = 1
}
```

if you expect the runtime attribute value of '0' to perhaps map to `.None`

Comment: This still didn't work. Plus you can't do `case None = 0` unless your enum is declared like `enum ButtonBackgroundColor : NSInteger`

Comment: Thanks; updated to add ': Int' - just looking to help you map a `0` in some UI design window to your enumeration...

Answer (score 0):

@GoZoner's answer didn't work for me. Tried changing the raw type to `String` and that didn't work as well. My solution is to define another variable (of whichever type supported by the runtime attributes) and then override the `didSet` of that variable to set the enum.

So in code:

```
var IBButtonBackgroundColor = "None"
{
    didSet
    {
        switch self.IBButtonBackgroundColor
        {
            case "None":
                self.backgroundColorType = .None
                break

            case "Yellow":
                self.backgroundColorType = .Yellow
                break
            default:
                self.backgroundColorType = .None
                break
        }
    }
}
var backgroundColorType:ButtonBackgroundColor = .None
```

I don't like having to repeat things in the switch/case, but I can't think of any better solution for now.

Comment: You can set the raw value of the `enum` as `String` with values `"None"`, `"Yellow"`... and the use the initializer from raw value and use `.None` if `nil` is returned.

Comment: @MarcoBoschi Yes, I tried that too. But it doesn't when it's runtime user defined for some reason. I get key-value encoding error